# smallest equivalence relation containing pairs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let R = {a,b,c,d,e}. Give the smallest equivalence relation on A containing the pairs (a,c),(a,e), and (b,d)

I have been looking at this problem and just do not know where to start. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Since the equivalence relation is symmetric, $(c,a)$, $(e,a)$, and $(d,b)$ must be in your relation. Since it is reflexive $(a,a), (b,b), \ldots$ must be related. Then take the [transtitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) and you're done

Comment: Thank You! The transitive closure was the only part I was stuck on but was able to figure it out.

Comment: What is A???????